# Why am I not able to change the value of the boolean variable in this method

Tags: java, algorithm

```
   public static void isMatchHelper(String input, String pattern, boolean ret){
        if(pattern.length() == 0 && input.length() == 0){
            ret =  true;
        }
        else if(pattern.length() == 0){
            ret =  false;
        }
        else if(input.length() == 0){
            ret =  true;
        }
        if(pattern.length() == 0 || input.length() == 0){
                return;
        }
        else if(pattern.charAt(0) == input.charAt(0)){
                isMatchHelper(input.substring(1), pattern.substring(1), ret);
        }
        if(pattern.charAt(0) == '.'){
            isMatchHelper(input, pattern.substring(1), ret);
        }
        if(pattern.charAt(0) == '*'){
            if(pattern.length() > 1){
                int countMatches = 0;
                char compareWith = pattern.charAt(countMatches + 1);
                while( countMatches != input.length() && input.charAt(countMatches) == compareWith){
                    countMatches++;
                }
                isMatchHelper(input.substring(countMatches), pattern.substring(2), ret);
            }
            else{
                ret =  true;
            }
        }
        if(pattern.charAt(0) != input.charAt(0)){
            isMatchHelper(input, pattern.substring(1), ret);
        }

    }
```

Ive tried input where it enters the first input, and ret is true, but then again, the  value of ret when I check it is still false. I know this probably has to do with pass by value, I tried passing a Boolean Object, and using the Boolean.FALSE, or Boolean.TRUE, that didn't work. I passed a boolean array with 1 parameter, and that worked.

My question is now more or a less a conceptual one, to improve my understanding, I'd like to know why the boolean didn't work as planned. Is this a pass by value concern, or something else? I must admit, at some point I thought using Boolean vs boolean might be the fix.

I look forward to your help.

Comment: I don't think you can override a parameter you pass into the function.

Comment: `bool` is primitive so a copy of parameter value is created. I guess `java.lang.Boolean` will also not help as it is immutable, best bet is to change the way you wrote the function use return values instead of parametr

Comment: @Puru--, Yeah the primitive wrappers are immutable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since this is Java, you cannot pass a parameter by reference.

Instead, just return the value from the method.

```
   public static boolean isMatchHelper(String input, String pattern) {
       boolean ret;
       .... // Rest of your code
       .... // Replace all return statements with return ret;
      return ret;
   }
```

Just to be clear, since the function is recursive, you can change recursive calls exactly as you would change non-recursive calls:

This line

```
isMatchHelper(input, pattern.substring(1), ret);
```

Becomes this line:

```
ret = isMatchHelper(input, pattern.substring(1));
```

Comment: its a recursive function.

Comment: @ShahrukhKhan, Are you implying that you cannot change the return type of a recursive function?

Comment: @ShahrukhKhan, I just updated the answer to more specifically address the recursive calls.